# PostgreSql - .Net-EfCore Limitation Is Not Added

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am creating a table in PostgreSQL using the .Net-EFCore with a model-first approach. The view of the table in the migration looks like the image you provided. However, I have a problem in that when the column I want to limit with max-length is created in the database, no limitation is added.

[Table Image On Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW1t4.png)

[Created Migration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LsTH.png)

The column named "problem_id" is of type varchar. In PostgreSQL, constraints can be applied to varchar columns, and that's how it's being used in this case to impose a limitation.

I tried to limit it with HasMaxLength, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by defining it as `HasColumnType("VARCHAR(100)")` to set the maximum limit.

Note: When I tried to set the maximum limit using both FluentAPI and DataAnnotations, it didn't work.